# Nginx forward requests to the new URL

Tags: http, nginx, url, proxypass

How can i change url for site in Docker?

This conf work fine

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

but with this conf not work

```
location /newurl/ {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Take 404 not found for scripts,css files.

Can anybody tell me about configuration nginx, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to replace the /newurl/ with command

```
location /newurl/ {
     rewrite ^/newurl/(.*)$ /$1 break;
     ...
```

Comment: Try now, nothing change

Comment: If you want to get some files or something, you should use root or alias to static folder, and you need to change owner to user www-data or user you're setting in nginx.conf

Comment: I try to explain my problem, but I fail.
I need to make location / work the same as location / name
Rules is not the problem, because 1 of 2 configurations works